# Error inflating class fragment with class using FragmentActivity

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, xamarin, android-fragmentactivity, inflate-exception

I have coded a `Google Maps` application in `Xamarin`, and am getting this error:

> Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error
>   inflating class fragment

I am getting this error when the following line of code is run:

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MapWithOverlayLayout);
```

Here is my `MapWithOverlayLayout.axml` layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <fragment class="SimpleMapDemo.MapWithMarkersActivity"
            android:id="@+id/mapWithOverlay"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The namespace is called: `SimpleMapDemo`

Here is my class declaration:

```
public class MapWithMarkersActivity : Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity
```

I am using a `SupportMapFragment` object to display a Google Map

Can I please have some help to get this code working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out myself. I did not have the correct class name.

Here is the correct layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the class attribute you set on the fragment element. Have you tired inflating the layout without it?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and fixed it by deleting the AndroidManifest in the obj/Debug/android directory, in the VS or XS and rewriting it so that it only works on me

That is because the app can't distinguish between google play services manifest and the app's one.